# What does (not provided) mean in the traffic sources section of google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking at Google Analytics for one of our sites, and I noticed that our top Keyword is 
`(not provided)`.  This seems like a special value of some kind, I can't imagine people typing 
`(not provided)` into the search and coming up with our site.

Does it mean that a large number of our site users don't use cookies?  I don't understand, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the referrer was either [blocked](http://searchengineland.com/google-to-begin-encrypting-searches-outbound-clicks-by-default-97435), didn't exist or was an [encrypted Gmail user](http://www.business2community.com/seo/google-analytics-not-provided-is-a-double-standard-0150706).