# Google analytics not provided for 55% of total traffic

Tags: google-analytics, not-provided

I've been [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30776/google-analytics-traffic-source-search-engine-not-provided) and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28675/what-does-not-provided-mean-in-the-traffic-sources-section-of-google-analytics) to learn what `(not provided)` means. Now the question is if what I am seeing in my Google Analytics stats for my website is considered normal (and whether I can/should do anything about it).

Here are the statistics from one day, but other days are similar:

102 visits, 57 is from `(not provided)`, that's over 55% of unknown keywords.

Is it normal to have it like that? Does google plan to do anything about it? In other words, what's the perspective? In my understanding, with this approach, as people switch to `https`, Analytics will stop being useful. Please correct me if I am wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: I prefer got get my privacy untouched. So I hope Google's plan is NOT to do anything about it...

Comment: @TheDisintegrator: my point is - encryption of google search for signed in users is to protect your privacy against 3rd party, such as the internet provider. You still trust Google in giving them your password and your keywords (and your email data and many more). So they should be able to summarize and pass this *anonymous* data to users of analytics, regardless of whether search was encrypted or not. It does not hurt your privacy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't whether Google will do anything about it, it's whether Google can.  Here's an interesting article, link below, about what's being referred to as "Dark Social" (Chat, ICQ, Typed, Email clients, etc.)

http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/10/dark-social-we-have-the-whole-history-of-the-web-wrong/263523/

You're number 55% seems to be around what most sites see in the `(not provided)` category.

Also, https on your site shouldn't affect Google analytics results.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think Google can and should, it's their search engine after all. I see no difference in how results should be interpreted, whether encrypted or not.

Comment: The problem is that if a link is typed, copy&pasted, or event clicked on from a mail client there's no way for the browser (FF, Chrome, IE, Safari) to tell what clicked the link so they can't set a referrer which means to GA it's as if the user typed the URL directly.

Comment: I am more interested in people coming from google search, as they used to be 95% of my traffic. In this case the link was never taken out of google, so it should pass data to analytics correctly, right?